# Docker routing into ipvlan from host network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, routes, vlan

**Goal:**
I like to be able to ping and access the docker clients from my host network. And if possible, I like to have as much as possible configured in my docker-compose.yml.

*Remark:
ICMP (ping) is just used for simplification. Actually, I like to access ssh on 22 and some other ports. Mapping ports is my current solution, but since I have many docker client container it becomes messy.*

```
  ___________        ___________         ___________ 
 |   host   |        |  docker  |       |  docker  |
 |  client  |        |   host   |       |  client  |   
 | ..16.50  |  <-->  | ..16.10  |       |          |
 |          |        | ..20.1   | <-->  | ..20.5   |
 |          |                           |          |
 |          |  <----- not working ----> |          |
```

**Problem:**
I am able to ping my docker host from docker clients and host clients, but not the docker clients from host clients.

That's my configuration on ubuntu 22.04.

```
docker host:               192.168.16.10/24
client host network:       192.168.16.50/24
default gw host network:   192.168.161  /24
docker client (container): 192.168.20.5 /24
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  ipvlan20:
    name: ipvlan20
    driver: ipvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: enp3s0.20
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: br-ipvlan20
      ipvlan-mode: l3
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.20.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.20.1"
          
services:
  portainer:
    image: alpine
    hostname: ipvlan20
    container_name: ipvlan20
    restart: always
    command: ["sleep","infinity"]
    
    dns: 192.168.16.1
    networks:
      ipvlan20:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.20.5
```

On my docker host, I added the following link with the vlan gateway IP.

```
ip link add myipvlan20 link enp3s0.20 type ipvlan mode l3
ip addr add 192.168.20.1/24 dev myipvlan20
ip link set myipvlan20 up
```

And on my host client, I added a rout to the docker host for the docker client network.

```
ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.16.10
```

**I tried also:**

Do I have to use macvlan? I tried that, but also unsuccessfully.

Do I have to use l3? I also tried with l2, but unsuccessfully as well.

Comment: How do you assign IP addresses to individual processes without containers?  Why is sending ICMP echo packets an important task to you?  (Can you use Compose `ports:` to make a container visible on its host's IP address(es), the same as a non-container process?)

Comment: @David Maze I have many containers forwarding the ports would be possible and this is my current solution. Since I have many containers, I would prefer to access the containers with their IP and standard port. ICMP (ping) is just used for simplification. Actually, I like to access ssh on 22 and some other ports. (Thanks for the question will clarify my post)I have many containers forwarding the ports would be possible and this is my current solution but since I have many containers I would prever to access the containers with their IP and standard port.